# fortran read statement

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Newbie question, but I can't find some good fortran documentation anywhere.

I am studying a program and the writer uses a read statement to evaluate if the user wants to rerun the script.

The code is:

```
PRINT *,'Calculate again? .TRUE./T/t -> yes , .FALSE./F/f -> no'
READ *,answer
```

Then it uses the logical variable answer to select where does the program have to goto next.

What does the code above do?

Comment: The dot instead of a correct comma in `READ *.answer` is probably just a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably it is supposed to be `READ *, answer` to read *answer* from the standard input unit.

The code outputs "Calculate again? .TRUE./T/t -> yes , .FALSE./F/f -> no" then reads into `answer`, which I suppose is declared as a logical variable.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features for documentation of Fortran 95.

Answer (score 3):

M.S.B is right, I just add what did not fit into a comment.

There are tons of good Fortran resources on the internet. You can use official standard, but better are usually documantation for compilers. This one [http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v111v131/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlf131.aix.doc%2Flanguage_ref%2Fassociatestmt.html](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v111v131/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlf131.aix.doc/language_ref/associatestmt.html) is very good.

Also there are numerous courses and tutorials. Just google "Fortran beginner course", "Fortran tutorial" or similar.